# DISCORD.JS | How would I make a promote and demote command

Tags: discord.js

How would I make a promote / demote command that would give a tagged user the higher rank / lower rank?

I've been told about mapping roles but I am not this advanced, any examples would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an array of role IDs, starting with the lowest rank and ending with the highest. Then you could compare the roles the user already has with the roles in the array and give / remove the next role.

This is easier with a database, but this should do the trick.

Also small tip, always provide code here and show you did some work. People here are extremely mean towards new people and inexperienced developers. If you want help from nicer people, I suggest asking on Discord servers like The Coding Den or DiscordJS ^^

Comment: Thanks for the advice :), will take this information on.